# Shrink databases in case a database split

Tags: sql-server, database, shrink

Due to a new architecture I have to split the current database in 2 databases both of them having 50% of the initial database (= 15GB).

**1/ Is this a good idea to execute `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (0)`** for the 2 newly created databases? I'm asking this as I've read many articles stating the shrinking database leads to fragmentation.

**2/ Is a good approach to set both databases as SIMPLE recovery** while doing the separation and then to set it to FULL back?

What is the action you recommend to apply in this cases?

Comment: Let's move that to dba.stackexchange.com - this is not a development question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrinking obviously is there is no chance the space gets reiused. THat said ,the database initially is on the really tiny size - I have databases here that have multiple files and earch is larger. So, the gain may simply not worth it.

But it is a valid case for shrinking IF the database will not grow back in reasonable time and you need the space.

Comment: One of databases have a small increase rate, but the other is increasing faster.

Comment: So what is the sense of shrinking them if they grow up again? THat is then a classical no case unless they take years (multiple=) to grow back. And even then they are TINY.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear now: only the DB that will grow slowly needs to be shrinked, while the other database should not be shrinked.